# How do I optimize rendering the following HTML snippet

Tags: html

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><img src="http://www.foo.com/a.img"></img></td>
     <td><img src="http://www.foo.com/a.img"></img></td>
     <td><img src="http://www.foo.com/a.img"></img></td>
     <td><img src="http://www.foo.com/a.img"></img></td>
     <td><img src="http://www.foo.com/a.img"></img></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above code snippet shows 5 `<td>` elements inside a `<tr>`. All contents within the `<td>` are similar. Is there a way to optimize this so that I can handle this through some form of a repetition (e.g. much similar to a for loop).

Comment: Are you asking how to produce this HTML in a more efficient manner? If so what language are you using? Otherwise I don't believe there is any way to short cut this in raw HTML, without using JavaScript or some server-side code to generate it.

Comment: you can have a background repeat

Comment: @Sam - I am using java to html generator to generate this code dynamically which in turn gets stored in the database. I am running into storage problems while storing the HTML, hence I would like to optimize the size of the HTML which is being generated.

Comment: OK thanks. You could use CSS to reduce the size of the HTML markup - i.e. move the IMG SRC attribute value out of the code. But unless you can do generation closer to the client, you're going to be stuck with all of the <TD> elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type='text/css'>
   .imageRepeat {
      width: 200px; /* image width*/
      height:1000px; /* height times the number of images */
      background-image: url('http://www.foo.com/a.img');
   }
</style>

<div class='imageRepeat'>
<!-- place holder for background image -->

</div>
```

the empty div will hold the place to display the images x number of times you want.
That is if you are trying to repeat the same image;

Answer (score 0):

If all the images need to be different (or if you can't use background-image for some reason), I'd float the images:

```
<style>
img.float {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
}
</style>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" class="float" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt=""class="float" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt=""class="float" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt=""class="float" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt=""class="float" />
```

This will display all the images on their own line.